# Referencing two spinners together?

Tags: java, android

So basically I have two spinners, one of which is the day of the week Mon, Tues, Weds etc.. the other contains four numbers 0732, 3735, 0736 and 0737. Is it possible to add an if statement say position 1 (Monday) + position 2 (0736) = new variable Mon36. Any help would be appreciated thanks ?

```
    final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_dotw);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.dotw_array, R.layout.custom_spinner);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(
                        AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    showToast("spinnerdotw: position= " + position + "id=" + id);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    showToast("No Dotw selected");
                }


            });

    final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_pg);

    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.pg_array, R.layout.custom_spinner);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    final String porition1;


    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(
                        AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                   spinner2position = position;

                   }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    showToast("No Pg selected");

                }

            });

 private void spinnerPos() {
    if (spinner1position + spinner2position == 0) ;
    {
        TextView sonyR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        sonyR.setText(" sunday and pg32 have been selected ");

        Log.i(String.valueOf(sonyR), "pos");

    }if
      (spinner1position + spinner2position == 1)
        {
        TextView sonyR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        sonyR.setText(" Monday and pg32 have been selected ");

        Log.i(String.valueOf(sonyR), "pos");
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and say yes, that's possible. I can't say anything about *how*, though, without more details.

Comment: What do you need my friend ?

Comment: The code for your spinners for example. And more info on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I added a snippet of my spinner code if that helps ?

Comment: I see you already started working on a solution. What was your problem with that? *\*saw before you edited it out.*

Comment: for some reason the value didn't changed and the Textview always output the one result and wouldn't switch to the other.

Comment: I assume that `spinner1position` and `spinner2position` are instance variables of your Activity?

Comment: Adding to that, where exactly do you call `spinnerPos()`?

Comment: Yes they are instances.  I din't, should it be added below onselected?

Comment: Well, yes, if you don't call the code, it won't be executed.

Comment: it returns incompatible type return void when I try referencing it with int spinner2position. Any ideas how to resolve ?

Comment: Well, you defined return type `void` for method `spinnerPos()`, so you naturally cannot return anything.

Comment: what do you suggest ?

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code:

In the `OnItemSelectedListener()` for `spinner1`, **you don't set `spinner1position`**, so it will never get updated:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
    new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(
            AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            showToast("spinnerdotw: position= " + position + "id=" + id);
        }

        \\ ...

    });
```

You also **never call `spinnerPos()`** in your `OnItemSelectedListener()`, so the text on the UI will never be updated.

A better version of your `OnItemSelectedListener` would be this:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
    new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            spinner1position = position;

            spinnerPos();

            showToast("spinnerdotw: position= " + position + "id=" + id);
        }

        \\ ...

    });
```

Same for `spinner2`.

---

I also have a few errors in method `spinnerPos()`:

```
if (spinner1position + spinner2position == 0) ;
    {
        TextView sonyR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        sonyR.setText(" sunday and pg32 have been selected ");

        Log.i(String.valueOf(sonyR), "pos");

    }
```

The **semicolon directly after the `if`** clause looks like a typo. Your conditions don't really make sense, either -- you would have to look at each value independently and not at the sum.